# -- operator not working javascript

Tags: javascript, decrement

hello guys i am trying to work on the setInterval function my code is:

```
var int = setInterval(function() {
    var x = 0;
    x--;
    document.body.innerHTML = x;
}, 30);
```

but all this does is prints -1 nothing more why is it like this can anybody tell me?

Comment: because you're setting the variable to 0 every time it runs and then subtracting 1. You'll always get -1

Comment: What do you expect it to do? Why?

Comment: You need to move the variable declaration out of the function.

Comment: `var x = 0` is going to reset the value of `x` each time. Try declaring `x` outside of the `setInterval` call, eg: `var x = 0; var int = setInterval(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are declaring the variable inside the function and the function is called every 30ms (this is the nature of setInterval) it will create a new variable x and assign 0 to it, then subtract 1 from it. Thus it will be -1 every time. To fix it you can do:

```
var x = 0;
var int = setInterval(function() {
  x--;
  document.body.innerHTML = x;
}, 30);
```

Although fair warning: this will result in an infinite loop

Comment: `Although fair warning: this will result in an infinite loop` not exactly, since it's not really a loop - it will schedule the code to be run an infinite amount of times. It sounds like tomayto-tomahto but it's an important distinction, an infinite loop suggests the program will be stuck there and is most often denoting a problem. By comparison, `setInterval` is not going to prevent other code from running. Also, it can be terminated by doing `clearInterval(int)` from any part of the application, as opposed to only having the option of `break` or `return` inside the loop structure.